# show that $C(C[u])=K[u]$

Tags: vector-spaces, diagonalization

> Let $E$ be a $K$-vector space of dimension $n$, and $u$ be a diagonalizable linear map from $E$ to $E$.
>
> Let $C[u]$ be the set of linear maps from $E$ to $E$ which commute with $u$. In other words,
>
> $C[u] = \left\{ v \text{ linear map from $E$ to $E$ such that $ v \circ u=u \circ v$} \right\}$.
>
> More generally, for any subset $X$ of $L(E) = \left(\text{vector space of linear maps from $E$ to itself}\right)$, we let $C(X)$ be the set of all elements $\in L(E)$ which commute with all elements of $X$.
>
> How can we show that $C(C[u])=K[u]$?
>
> Here, $K[u]$ is the set of all $P(u) \in L(E)$ such that $P$ is a polynomial.

I see that any element of $K[u]$ can commute with all the linear maps which can commute with $u$

but showing that any of them is  polynomial of $u$ seems an interesting result.

I can write $E=E_{\lambda_1} \oplus... \oplus E_{\lambda_k}$ such as $sp(u)=$ { $\lambda_{1}$, ... , $\lambda_{k}$} (spectra)

How can we continue?

Comment: swith=commute, $K$-vectoriel=$K$-vector space, polynome=polynomial.

Comment: Hint: Let $S$ be the set of eigenvalues of $u$. Write $E = \bigoplus_{\lambda \in S} E_\lambda$, where the $E_\lambda$ are the eigenspaces of $\lambda \in S$. Argue that each endomorphism of $E$ that preserves all these eigenspaces $E_\lambda$ must commute with $u$ and thus belongs to $C\left[u\right]$. Thus, in turn, any element of $C\left(C\left[u\right]\right)$ must commute with all such endomorphisms, and hence (check this!) must act as a scalar $k_\lambda$ on each $E_\lambda$. This means (prove this using Lagrange interpolation) that it is a polynomial in $u$.

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem?  In particular, do the words "Schur's lemma" mean anything to you?

Comment: @JacobManaker i'v never heard about it before

Comment: @darijgrinberg "Thus, in turn, any element of C(C[U])  must commute with all such endomorphismes " why is it true ?